# Calculate lags and update flags after comparing years

Tags: sas

suppose to have the following:

> ```
>   ID      yS     yE     flagS     FlagE   
>  0001   2015    2017      1         1
>  0001   2017    2020      2         2      
>  0002   2017    2018      1         1          
>  0002   2019    2020      2         2
> ```

I'm trying to generate the following:

> ```
>   ID      yS     yE     flagS     FlagE   
>  0001   2015    2017      1         1
>  0001   2017    2020      2         1   
>  0002   2017    2018      1         1          
>  0002   2019    2020      2         2
> ```

meaning: flagE at the second row becomes equal to the flag at the first row (i.e., 1) because yE at the first row = 2017 is equal to yS at the second row, i.e., 2017.
Conversely, for ID=0002 nothing should be done because there is a gap between end and start in terms of years.
I tried the lag function on yE to then compare the year yS and yE but it performs the lag of the entire variable on the other IDs. Also using first.ID it does not work.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Provide a reproducible example, i.e. more than 1 ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives you the expected output

- Sort by descending `id` `yS`
- Simulate the [`leading`](https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2015/06/19/can-you-lag-and-lead-at-the-same-time-if-using-the-sas-data-step-yes-you-can/) function with the merging trick
- Apply desired flag if the given condition is true
- Sort back the output by ascending `id` `yS` to get expected format

```
proc sort data=have out=stage1;
    by id descending ys;
run;

data stage2;
    merge stage1 stage1(firstobs=2 keep=ye flage id rename=(ye=_ye flage=_flage 
        id=_id));

    if id ne _id then
        call missing(_ye, _flage, _id);

    if _ye=ys then
        flage=_flage;
    drop _:;
run;

proc sort data=stage2 out=want;
    by id ys;
run;
```

`want`

```
  id   yS   yE  flagS flagE
 0001 2015 2017   1     1
 0001 2017 2020   2     1
 0002 2017 2018   1     1
 0002 2019 2020   2     2
```